# AWS with existing TCP Server implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, server, iot

I have an existing AWS solution which includes the following.  It uses a legacy application (written in C#) running on an EC2 instance. This legacy application implements a TCP server and listens on a specific TCP port.  It contains custom code to decode the data and dump it into a database.  The choice of the database is less important for now.

I'm after a more contemporary solution based on AWS which can potentially deprecate the existing legacy application.  Most options with Amazon IoT involve HTTP and MQTT. I can't change the protocol.  It must still be a TCP.

The closest thing I can find is  Amazon IoT Greengrass (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/converting-industrial-protocols-with-aws-iot-greengrass/) which appears to involve running a TCP client in an AWS lambda function, and then forwarding it to MQTT / AWS IoT Core.

I'm curious what other approaches may be possible.

Comment: *"I can't change the protocol. It must still be a TCP."*  You might want to clarify the reason for this restriction.  Both HTTP and MQTT can (and usually do) ride inside TCP connections so it's hard to understand why you say those are not acceptable.

Comment: Because I have many IoT devices in the field which have existing firmware.  I can't visit each one and upgrade them.  I want to continue using them as is.

Comment: Thanks, this is a reasonable constraint.  I just wanted to clarify.